# Nvidia X server's setting empty after kernel update!

Tags: drivers, nvidia

After an update executed by my update manager, the latest kernel was installed and I restarted my PC. After the update was complete, there was a message in the top right corner:

> your system is currently running without video hardware acceleration

When I entered my driver manager, it looked like the newest driver was selected, but my "Nvidia X server settings" were empty. The problem is, that, whenever I start my PC, the above message comes up.

I would appreciate your feedback / help :)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu!   Please, can you provide a  screenshot /  photo - and/or some other context?  It would really help :) + as well as which version of: Your Ubuntu,  Your Nidia (card + driver)